# Problema na persistência de dados utilizando JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc

Tenho uma classe que tem dois atributos, horário de inicio e horário final, ambos do tipo Date.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horarioInicio;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horarioFinal;
```

Na camada de visualização está sendo utilizado o recurso de Data Binding do Spring, mas ao submeter o formulário com os dados, tenho como retorno o código de status 400, indicando que há algum problema na requisição. Quando os dois campos são removidos, o formulário é submetido normalmente. Lembrando que o objeto de comando já faz parte da visão.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <form:label path="horarioInicio">Horario inicio</form:label>
    <form:input id="horarioInicio" path="horarioInicio" class="form-control input-sm" type="time" />
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <form:label path="horarioFinal">Horario final</form:label>
    <form:input id="horarioFinal" path="horarioFinal" class="form-control input-sm" type="time" />
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/salvarManutencao")
public String saveFornecedor(@ModelAttribute("manutencao") Manutencao manutencao,
        @ModelAttribute("produtosManutencao") HashMap<Long, Long> produtosManutencao, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "/manutencao/save/saveManutencao";

    manutencaoService.saveManutencao(manutencao, produtosManutencao);
    return "redirect:fornecedores";
}
```

Ambos atributos fazem parte da classe Manutenção.

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem 2 erros, o primeiro é o seu `BindingResult` que deve ser declarado como parâmetro **após** o objeto a ser validado, do jeito como está, irá validar somente `produtosManutencao`

Faça assim:

```
@RequestMapping("/salvarManutencao")
public String saveFornecedor(
        @ModelAttribute("manutencao") Manutencao manutencao,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        @ModelAttribute("produtosManutencao") HashMap<Long, Long> produtosManutencao
) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "/manutencao/save/saveManutencao";

    manutencaoService.saveManutencao(manutencao, produtosManutencao);
    return "redirect:fornecedores";
}
```

Colocando o `bindingResult` após `@ModelAttribute("manutencao") Manutencao manutencao` ele realizará a validação corretamente, não exibindo apenas o erro 400 (bad request)

Após isso você vai receber outro erro, mas dessa vez por quê o Spring não conseguiu lidar com o formato da data.

Para resolver o segundo problema, terá de informar o padrão da data, assim:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horarioInicio;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horarioFinal;
```